# Prevent Tensosflow Dataset from resetting the generator on multiple model.predict calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using tensorflow Dataset from_generator method to make predictions using a CNN model on different batches. But I want to add some extra logic after every batch prediction. Specifically, I want to aggregate different results.

Here is my generator function:

```
def gen_predict(img_no):
  img_data = nib.load('./testing-images/10' + '%02d' %img_no + '_3.nii.gz').get_fdata()
  patch_size = 23
  dist_center = (patch_size - 1) // 2
  l, b, h = img_data.shape
  for zc in range(dist_center, h - dist_center - 1):
    for yc in range(dist_center, b - dist_center - 1):
      for xc in range(dist_center, l - dist_center - 1):    
        print(xc,yc,zc) 
        xl, yl, zl = (xc - dist_center, yc - dist_center, zc - dist_center)
        xr, yr, zr = (xc + dist_center, yc + dist_center, zc + dist_center)
        cartesianCoordinate = np.array([xc, yc, zc])
        spectralCoordinates = np.array([0, 0, 0])
        X = (np.array(img_data[xl:(xr + 1), yl:(yr + 1), zl:(zr + 1)]), np.concatenate((cartesianCoordinate, spectralCoordinates)).reshape((6,1)))
        yield (X,)
```

The problem is that after every predict call the generator resets and on next predict call it gives the predictions for same set of data. Here is my code:

```
dataset_pred = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: gen_predict(3), ((tf.float32, tf.float32),), output_shapes=((tf.TensorShape([23,23,23]), tf.TensorShape([6,1])),))
dataset_pred = dataset_pred.batch(BS)
for i in range(num_batches):
  temp_pred = np.array(model.predict(dataset_pred, batch_size=BS, steps=1))
  ## aggregate the temp_pred result ##
```

I want to mimic the `model.predict(dataset_pred, batch_size=BS, steps=num_batches)` behaviour with that extra logic. Also, I can't store the result of this call due to large num_batches.

**EDIT:** I have added the answer. But will really appreciate any help to increase the efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Basically, we can store the corresponding generator in a variable and then use lambda to make it callable. That doesn't reset the generator.

```
cur_gen = gen_predict(img_no)
dataset_pred = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: cur_gen, ((tf.float32, tf.float32),), output_shapes=((tf.TensorShape([23,23,23]), tf.TensorShape([6,1])),))
dataset_pred = dataset_pred.batch(BS)
for i in range(num_batches):
  temp_pred = np.array(model.predict(dataset_pred, batch_size=BS, steps=1))
  ## aggregate the temp_pred result ##
```